# Принудительный выход пользователем из приложения . Избежать краха приложения

Tags: ios, swift, usercontrol, users, uiviewcontroller

При первом запуске приложения, пользователь должен пройти несколько view, заполнить их (Они все связанны NavigationController'ом) и тогда его перекидывает на  TabBarController, где он  дальше пользуется приложением. 
Когда он заходит второй раз, то сразу переходит на TabBarController.

Но если я закрываю полностью приложение до окончания прохождения всех начальных view, меня перекидывает , но поля в настройках пустые(имя и т.д.)
А бывает что приложение и вовсе не открывается.

Как можно сделать чтобы пользователь после закрытия вернулся на те view, которые он не прошел или вернуть его на самый первый экран .

Вот пока что у меня есть .

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {


    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let def = UserDefaults.standard
    let homeController: UIViewController

    let is_authenticated = def.bool(forKey: "is_authenticated") // return false if not found or stored value

    if is_authenticated {
        //user logged in
        homeController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBarControllerid") as! UITabBarController // create instance of HomeController or from Storyboard

    } else {
        homeController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NavigationControllerid") as! UINavigationController
    }
    saveLoggedState()

    window?.rootViewController = homeController // change rootViewController to HomeController
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible() // show window

    return true
}
```

Comment: Добавляете новое поле `status`.  Каждое view это отдельный статус. При последовательном заполнении статус меняется. При открытии приложения проверяете статус и кидаете в нужное view.

Answer (score 1):

Где-то, в недрах вашего приложения, значение для ключа "is_authenticated" (в UserDefaults) сохраняется несвоевременно, слишком рано. Сохраняйте его только после того, когда пользователь заполнит все ваши экраны, а не (вероятно, у вас так) до этого.

Comment: Это хорошая идея ! Как бы мне это реализовать, если тут я это делаю в методе который  отвечает за запуск приложухи

Comment: Это не идея, это надо просто перенести пару строчек кода в другое место ) Я же говорю: где-то в своем приложении, вы устанавливаете этот ключ в true, так вот перенесите это действие на тот момент, когда пользователь полностью пройдет экраны, где нужно что-то заполнять. А сейчас у вас это происходит ПРЕДПОЛОЖИТЕЛЬНО во время открытия первого такого экрана. Просто я весь код не вижу и могу только догадываться.